# Change Shape OCI instance with Ansible

Tags: ansible, instance, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

It is possible to change shape for an Oracle Cloud Instance through Ansible? I did not find a module to do this ( i found only the get shapes module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the shape of the instance using the `oci_instance` module using a play like:

```
- name: Create Instance
  oci_instance:
    name: "example_name"
    image_id: "ocid1.image.oc1.iad.EXAMPLE"
    shape: "VM.Standard2.1"
    compartment_id: "ocid1.compartment.oc1..EXAMPLE"
    availability_domain: "IwGV:US-EXAMPLE-AD-1"
    vnic:
      subnet_id: "ocid1.subnet.oc1.iad.EXAMPLE"
  register: result

- name: Update Instance shape
  oci_instance:
    id: "{{ result.instance.id }}"
    shape: "VM.Standard1.1"
    state: "present"
```

The changes take a while to be reflected as the instance needs to be rebooted after the shape change process. You can view the shape change process happening on the OCI console page.

Comment: It worked, I only used the second task, since I already have an instance id.